# Jquery Datepicker in multiple fields and saving the inputs

Tags: jquery, input, datepicker, submit

I'm still learning and my newest project got me stuck on this:

Inside of a table to manage customers, I want to have an input field with a datepicker (https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/ using this) for every row, like this:

```
<td>
//some more content
    <div class="includeDatepicker">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker">
    </div>
</td>
```

the whole thing gets set up like this:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function () {
    jQuery('.datepicker').dateRangePicker({
    autoClose: true,
    singleDate : true,
    showShortcuts: false,
    singleMonth: true,
    startOfWeek: 'monday',
    separator : ' ~ ',
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
    time: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
});
```

Until here, it works fine. Then though:

1. The datepicker only appears for the first input field in the first row of the table and will appear only there even if the others are clicked. What can I do to add a datepicker to every input field? I'm already using a class selector. I have done my research on this and found some solutions, but I can't really wrap my head around it either way.
2. How would it be possible that the date written to the input fields is saved even when the page is refreshed?

I would greatly appreciate any help and I've done research before asking on here, but none of it was to great avail.

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried adding an id attribute to the <td> ? Add some logic so as to ensure that each <td> has an id and then try it. I think that ids are required on the <td>

Comment: Thank you! But shouldn't they have different IDs then? How would I do that since I'm only listing them once?

Comment: Yes in html each id on the elements should be unique. It depend on how you are building up the table contents. If it entered by hand then just assign each td a unique id i.e. <td id="includeDatepicker1"> ,  <td id="includeDatepicker2"> etc.. etc..

Comment: The table is build by looping through the customers.

Comment: Sorry just looking at it again and jQuery('.datepicker').dateRangePicker( ... assigns to each input in the table based on the class. You would need some kind of id on the text input though for when submitting the data so you know what entity you are saving.

Comment: So I can set IDs like "random-[different number for each input]" which I did now. Then how do I call the datepicker for every input of those? Still with ":input[id*='random']", I'm facing the same problem. Hah. This makes me go crazy. Still, thank you so far.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my first problem, I just put it as: jQuery(":input[id*='random']").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).dateRangePicker({ ... now. Do you maybe have thought on 2.?

Comment: Yep you would have to assign a callback function as part of the declaration hold on I'll find an example and post it into an answer....

Answer (score 1):

I think for 2nd part an approach like this :

```
jQuery("document").ready(function () {
    jQuery('.datepicker').dateRangePicker({
    autoClose: true,
    singleDate : true,
    showShortcuts: false,
    singleMonth: true,
    startOfWeek: 'monday',
    separator : ' ~ ',
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
    time: {
        enabled: true
    }
},function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' TO: ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
    );
});
```

Inside that function above you could then make an AJAX call to the DB but as I said earlier you will need some id on the element so you can pass it back to the service layer so as to ensure you know what entity they are updating....

Im am not sure what date range picker you are using but if the one I think then  plenty of examples @ http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

Add a new functions something like :

```
function updateDBWithVals(urlToServer,startDateFromFrontEnd,endDateFromFrontEnd,rowID) {    
    return $.ajax({
            url:            urlToServer,
            data:           {startDate : startDateFromFrontEnd, endDate: endDateFromFrontEnd, entityID: rowID},
            type:           "POST",                         
            success:        function(response) { 
                                    console.log(response);
                            },
            error:          function(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
        }); 
}
```

Now in your call back function just call it i.e.

```
function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' TO: ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    updateDBWithVals("urlToYourServerLogic",start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),"theIDOfTheRow");
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to set different IDs or how to call them for the elements later on and I can't find anything for that searching on Google. What I did made them change on every page load which doesn't really achieve anything. I have only this one line (<input type="text" class="datepicker">) as the entire table is called in a loop to create a row for every customer.

Comment: Still, thank you for your help, I just feel pretty stupid lol.

Comment: If each row on the table is for a customer then you could apply a html id attribute to that row as part of the table creation. The id could just be the primary key of the customer from the DB or something that would allow you to do a lookup and update their data in the DB. In the function then when it is called you could use JQuery to grab the parent row html ID and pass it to the AJAX call .. Don't give up everything is achievable. Maybe put what you have so far into a JSFiddle and we can take it from there...

Comment: Can I marry you or at least honor you a thousand times on here? Just kidding, could you give me an example of how that call could look like? I managed to do the ID thing now.